# Add a legend in plotly button graph

Tags: r, button, plotly, legend

With plotly in R, I want to use the buttons to change the data. I've almost managed to make the graph I wanted, except that the legend doesn't appear. I tried adding
`name = ~B` but it doesn't work the way I want

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(
  A = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
  B = as.factor(rep(c("aaa", "bbb"), 4)),
  C = c(10, 90, 15, 85, 2, 98, 19, 81),
  couleur = rep(c("#eb927d", "#3cc7ed"), 4)
)

df2 <- data.table(
  A = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 , 6, 6)),
  B = as.factor(rep(c("aaa", "bbb"), 7)),
  C = c(10, 90, 15, 85, 2, 98, 19, 81, 40, 60, 20, 80, 64, 36),
  couleur = rep(c("#eb927d", "#3cc7ed"), 7)
)

buttons <- list(list(method = "restyle",args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE)), label = "button 1"),
                list(method = "restyle",args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),label = "button 2")
                )


plot_ly(data = df, x = ~ C, y = ~ A, type = "bar", marker = list(color = ~ couleur), visible = TRUE) %>%
  add_trace(data = df2, x = ~ C, y = ~ A, type = "bar", marker = list(color = ~ couleur),visible = FALSE) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack", updatemenus = list(list(buttons = buttons,direction = "down", 
                                                    pad = list("r", 10),showactive = TRUE,
                                                    x = 0.65,xanchor = "left",y = 1.1,yanchor = "top")))
```

Comment: Instead of using `markers = list(...`, use `color = ~B, colors = ~couleur`, for example: `plot_ly(data = df, x = ~ C, y = ~ A, type = "bar", color = ~B, colors = ~couleur)`